# Facebook Graph API get user wall data Objective C

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve a users wall posts. I have the following code but the results only retrieves the information of the User like its name, about, likes, etc. No data about its wall.

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"https://graph.facebook.com/wanamaoficial/feed?access_token=%@",
FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken]]; 

[request startWithCompletionHandler:
   ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *user, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
          NSLog(@"data2 %@",user);
      }
   }];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (i.e. without "graph.facebook.com" because it's implied in the query):

`FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"wanamaoficial/feed?access_token=%@",
FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken]];`